# Если обособленный член начинается с вводного слова, можно ли его отделять тире и запятой одновременно?

Tags: вводные-слова

> Суд в Киеве освободил бывшего командующего ПВО «донецких сепаратистов»
>   в Снежном Владимира Цемаха — вероятно, для выдачи его России в рамках
>   обмена.

Часть после тире — это обособленное обстоятельство?

Тогда надо было бы написать так:

"Суд в Киеве освободил бывшего командующего ПВО «донецких сепаратистов» в Снежном Владимира Цемаха, вероятно для выдачи его России в рамках обмена".

(Так как вводное в начале обособленного оборота не отделяется от него запятой.)

Но сейчас часто в публицистике наблюдается употребление тире. Например (https://theoryandpractice.ru/posts/17654-nauka-o-nevyskazannom-chto-takoe-kognitivnaya-lingvistika):

"В моей докторской диссертации «Анализ дискурса в когнитивной перспективе» я писал о том, что это ничуть не в меньшей степени когнитивное направление, но там важнее другие аспекты — например, не долговременная память, а оперативная, то, в каком порядке мы обрабатываем некий минимальный объем информации, как делимся ею с собеседником."

Правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания:

"Важнее другие аспекты — например, не долговременная память"?

Может быть, правильно было бы так написать:

"Важнее другие аспекты, например не долговременная память"?

Answer (score 1):

Отделять вводное слово тире и запятой одновременно можно. Это довольно часто наблюдается, в том числе и в литературе. Тире просто заменяет запятую и используется для подчёркивания следующей части.

В первом примере нет обособленного оборота. Без вводного слова запятой бы вообще не было. Тире употреблено для подчёркивания предположения, так как данная часть очень важна.

Запятая после "например" перед конкретным примером не ставится, исходя из материалов gramota.ru и этого источника:

https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/naprimer.html

Тогда получается, что запятой во втором примере быть не должно.

Answer (score 1):

Существует такое понятие, как **присоединительные конструкции**, которые подробно рассматриваются у Розенталя. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Это могут быть **разные** конструкции: слова, словосочетания, ряд однородных членов, целые предложения; для их присоединения используется союзная и бессоюзная связь.

**Примечание.** Одна и та же конструкция в разных предложениях может оформляться по-разному, поэтому всегда нужно **рассматривать предложение целиком**, а не брать из него отдельный фрагмент.

Все эти факторы учитываются при выборе знака, обычно запятой или тире.

**Вводные слова** могут выступать в роли **присоединительных союзов**, если оборот обособлен  запятой. Такие присоединительные обороты, как правило, не имеют значительной распространенности. В этом случае вводное слово не отделяется от оборота запятой.

Пример: ***Здесь важнее другие аспекты, например недолговременная память.***

Распространенный или осложненный оборот чаще обособляется **с помощью тире**, и такая связь является бессоюзной. Вводное слово уже не служит присоединительным союзом, а входит в состав оборот и обособляется.

Пример: ***Но там важнее другие аспекты — например, не долговременная память, а оперативная.***